# Sharepoint Calendar crawled events missing?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-calendar, crawled-property

I'm looking for the following crawled property (ows_q_DATE_EventDate) so I can map it to a managed property.

However when I look in the Search Service application under Crawled Properties it is missing from the list.

Is there something I am missing? In addition, is there a way of getting access to the Start AND End dates of a calendar event?
[image]

Comment: in order for properties to be crawled they need to have data in them, also it may have a different internal name so the crawl property would be another  crawled property name.

Answer (score 0):

the Start Date and End Date values for calendar items can be found in the following crawled properties:

Start Date: ows_EventDate
End Date: ows_EndDate

You can map these to managed properties to query their values.

Hope this helps!